# How to reload containing relations after saving the entity in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, model, cakephp-3.0

I have a code snippet as shown below;

```
// PurchaseController edit function. 
// created with bin/cake bake controller Purchase
if ($this->Purchases->save($purchase)) {
    echo $purchase->status->success_message;
}
```

To be more clear;

```
//before saving;
echo $purchase->status->success_message; //this gives purchase is drafted. 

//it should give after saving;
echo $purchase->status->success_message; //this should give purchase is sent.

//But it gives;
 echo $purchase->status->success_message; //this gives purchase is drafted.
```

However, although status_id is changing on my purchase entity, the "status" I reach on my purchase entity is not changing. How can I reload the relations to get the correct data?

**UPDATE:** I've just fixed it by loading statuses with lazy loading instead of eager loading. However I really think there should be a solution for this so I leave this question open for now.

Comment: I haven't upgraded to 3.0 but I remember 2 possible issues with saving relations: 1. Try to use `saveAll` 2. Are you sure your `$purchase` data array is arranged as it should?

Comment: purchase entity itself is perfectly correct. purchase->status_id gives what I want, which is the new saved data. But when I use relation on it, it does not bring the correct value. It just brings the old relation which I retrieved with get as before it is saved.  I will add more info to question to be more clear

Comment: How are you setting the `status_id` in `$purchase`?

Comment: @GregSchmidt by patching the entity